# /usr/include/linux discrepancies

Tags: updates, compiling

How do I ensure my header files in /usr/include/linux are updated?

**/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h**

and

**/usr/include/linux/bpf.h**
are significantly different where /usr/include/linux/bfp.h is out of date relative to the file in /src.

current uname -r output is 5.8.0-63-generic

I attempted all of the required updates such as

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
- sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
- sudo apt remove --purge linux-headers-*
- sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
- sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic
- sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04

Host has been rebooted.
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 138325 Jul  9 09:49 /usr/include/linux/bpf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160181 Jul 15 07:51 /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h

What am I missing and what can I do to get the more current bpf.h header installed without brute force that may impart compliation/run time problems if done incorrectly.

This was discovered when attempting to build bpftrace where

/usr/include/bpf/bpf.h

depends upon

/usr/include/linux/bpf.h     and this file is not up to date.

Comment: Hint : `/usr/include/linux/bpf.h` is provided by the package `linux-libc-dev` , i.e. support headers for userspace development. ... The headers in /usr/src/ are for "building kernel modules" only .

Comment: Upgrading linux-libc-dev did not help